# Determine precision of an instant in terms of minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc?

Tags: java, java-time

In java.time you can query the precision of a time unit:

```
java.time.Instant.now().query(java.time.temporal.TemporalQueries.precision())
```

When I do this I get a response that the instant has precision: `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit/NANOS`.

Is it possible to know whether an instant has only enough information to be: `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit/MINUTES` (or another time unit that can be packed into an instant, e.g. seconds, hours, etc)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Is it possible to know whether an instant has only enough information to be minutes"? Can you show some instants that _does_ have enough information to "be minutes", and some that doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
instant.truncatedTo( someChronoUnit ).equals( instant )
```

## Truncate

As you described, [`TemporalQueries.precision`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalQueries.html#precision()) returns a [`TemporalQuery<TemporalUnit>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html) that represents the *capability* of the data type, not the *contents* of an instance of that type.

I do not know of a direct way to determine the significant (non-zero) granularity of the content of an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). But you could hack a way by [truncating](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) for each level of granularity until finding a result that no longer matches the original `Instant` instance.

The [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum in Java defines the levels of granularity in *java.time*, and implements [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) interface. Loop through the relevant `ChronoUnit` enum objects (hours, minutes, seconds, nanos), truncating the target `Instant` object to each.

```java
for ( ChronoUnit unit : List.of( ChronoUnit.HOURS , ChronoUnit.MINUTES , ChronoUnit.SECONDS , ChronoUnit.NANOS ) )
{
    if ( instant.truncatedTo( unit ).equals( instant ) ) { return unit; }
}
```

Full example code.

```java
package work.basil.example.datetime;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Granularity
{
    private final static List < java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit > CHRONO_UNITS = List.of( ChronoUnit.HOURS , ChronoUnit.MINUTES , ChronoUnit.SECONDS , ChronoUnit.NANOS );

    public static ChronoUnit resolve ( final Instant instant )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( instant );
        for ( ChronoUnit unit : Granularity.CHRONO_UNITS )
        {
            if ( instant.truncatedTo( unit ).equals( instant ) ) { return unit; }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();  // Should never reach this point.
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2021-01-23T12:00:00.000000123Z" );
        ChronoUnit unit = Granularity.resolve( instant );
        System.out.println( "unit = " + unit );
    }
}
```

You could also do something similar by calling [`Instant#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#get(java.time.temporal.TemporalField)) for each part (each [`ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html)) to test for a non-zero value.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to compare the instant with another instant using the `truncatedTo` method.

For example

```
Instant one = Instant.now();
Instant two = Instant.ofEpochSecond(one.getEpochSecond());
System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(two);
Instant three = one.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(three);
```

This prints

```
2021-03-11T07:43:43.579704700Z
2021-03-11T07:43:43Z
2021-03-11T07:43:43Z
```

Two and three are equal.

In the general case, if a "raw" instant is equal to its truncated self based on a chrono unit (seconds, minutes, etc) then that instant has only enough information for the chrono unit specified.

Something like

```
boolean onlyEnoughFor(Instant instant, ChronoUnit unit) {
    return instant.truncatedTo(unit).equals(instant);
}
```